# Logistic regression - Under fitting

Tags: machine-learning, octave, logistic-regression

I am very very new to Machine learning..Trying to train my self with a course from Coursera. I am using Logistic regression for "winequality-white" Data. Sample of Data as below

```
7   0.27    0.36    20.7    0.045   45  170 1.001   3       0.45    8.8 6
6.3 0.3     0.34    1.6     0.049   14  132 0.994   3.3     0.49    9.5 6
8.1 0.28    0.4     6.9     0.05    30  97  0.9951  3.26    0.44    10  6
7.2 0.23    0.32    8.5     0.058   47  186 0.9956  3.19    0.4     9.9 6
7.2 0.23    0.32    8.5     0.058   47  186 0.9956  3.19    0.4     9.9 6
```

Last Column with value 6 Actually contains values from 3 to 9 Indicating Quality of wine. And rest of the Column contains various parameter to decide Quality of wine.

As per the Course I did build Cost function which returns J and Gradient. as below

```
function [J, grad] = lrCostFunction(theta, X, y, lambda)

  m = length(y); 
  J = 0;
  grad = zeros(size(theta));
  h = sigmoid(X * theta); % hypothisis for logistic regression
  J = (1/m) * sum( (-y .* log(h)) - ((1-y) .* log(1-h))) + (lambda/(2*m)) * sum(theta(2:length(theta)).^2);
  grad(1) = (1 / m) * ( X'(1,:)) * (h-y);
  grad(2:size(theta,1)) = (1/ m) * (X'(2:size(X',1),:)*(h-y) + ...
                        lambda*theta(2:size(theta,1),:));
  grad = grad(:);
end
```

This Cost Function I am calling from Another function to find the Theta Values

```
function [all_theta] = oneVsAll(X, y, num_labels, lambda)

% Some useful variables
m = size(X, 1);
n = size(X, 2);

% You need to return the following variables correctly 
all_theta = zeros(num_labels, n + 1);

% Add ones to the X data matrix
X = [ones(m, 1) X];

     for c = 1:num_labels  

%     % Set Initial theta
     initial_theta = zeros(n + 1, 1);
%     
%     % Set options for fminunc
     options = optimset('GradObj', 'on', 'MaxIter', 1000);
%     
      adc = c+2  ;
%     % Run fmincg to obtain the optimal theta
%     % This function will return theta and the cost 
     [theta] = ...
         fmincg (@(t)(lrCostFunction(t, X, (y == adc), lambda)), ...
                 initial_theta, options);

                 all_theta(c,:) = theta';

      end
end
```

With the help of all_theta I am predicting the Values( I did used training and validation sets as well) prediction is not at all correct.  Can some one help me where am I doing mistake.

This is my first ML model and funny part it is giving accuracy 2% :) .. Please help me to go in a correct direction. Thanks in advance

Note :- I am Using Octave.

I Also tried using Lambda values as 0.1, 0.01 , 0.001 etc. But no luck :(

Adding Prediction code ---

```
function p = predictOneVsAll(all_theta, X)

m = size(X, 1);
num_labels = size(all_theta, 1);

% You need to return the following variables correctly 
p = zeros(size(X, 1), 1);

% Add ones to the X data matrix
X = [ones(m, 1) X];

z = X * all_theta';
A = sigmoid(z);
[t,p]=max(A,[],2);
end
```

Comment: You might want to add some more tags to your question, to attract more people with relevant skillsets

Comment: Please post the prediction code also, then we can say anything.

Comment: Thanks Priyam for your Interest .. I have added prediction code